# Size discrepency between ELF CORE file and actual VM guest memory

Tags: elf, qemu, kvm, coredump

I have an ELF CORE file of a Windows 10 guest running in qemu/kvm generated using the qemu-monitor "dump-guest-memory" command. The memory allocated to this guest is 8 GB but the combined LOAD sections/segments of the CORE file is more than 8 GB i.e. about 82 MB more.

```
$ readelf -a dump1-libvirt.bin 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              CORE (Core file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         12
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0

There are no sections in this file.

There are no sections to group in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  NOTE           0x00000000000002e0 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000001320 0x0000000000001320         0x0
  LOAD           0x0000000000001600 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000a0000 0x00000000000a0000         0x0
  LOAD           0x00000000000a1600 0x00000000000a0000 0x00000000000a0000
                 0x0000000000010000 0x0000000000010000         0x0
  LOAD           0x00000000000b1600 0x00000000000c0000 0x00000000000c0000
                 0x0000000000004000 0x0000000000004000         0x0
  LOAD           0x00000000000b5600 0x00000000000c4000 0x00000000000c4000
                 0x000000000001c000 0x000000000001c000         0x0
  LOAD           0x00000000000d1600 0x00000000000e0000 0x00000000000e0000
                 0x0000000000020000 0x0000000000020000         0x0
  LOAD           0x00000000000f1600 0x0000000000100000 0x0000000000100000
                 0x000000007ff00000 0x000000007ff00000         0x0
  LOAD           0x000000007fff1600 0x0000000090000000 0x0000000090000000
                 0x0000000004000000 0x0000000004000000         0x0
  LOAD           0x0000000083ff1600 0x0000000094000000 0x0000000094000000
                 0x0000000004000000 0x0000000004000000         0x0
  LOAD           0x0000000087ff1600 0x000000009a500000 0x000000009a500000
                 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000         0x0
  LOAD           0x0000000087ff3600 0x0000000100000000 0x0000000100000000
                 0x0000000180000000 0x0000000180000000         0x0
  LOAD           0x0000000207ff3600 0x0000000812600000 0x0000000812600000
                 0x0000000000100000 0x0000000000100000         0x0
```

Does anyone have any idea what/why the extra 82 MB in the LOAD section captured in the core file?

I'm running qemu 4.1.1 compiled from source, machine type is pc-q35-4.1 and the guest machine is Windows 10 64 bit Version 1903 (OS build 18362).

Thanks.

Comment: What QEMU version and what machine do you use?

Comment: qemu 4.1.1 and machine is pc-q35-4.1. I've updated my post with more info. Thanks.